# How to merge multiple pdfs (or pngs) into one single page

Tags: bash, pdf, pdf-generation

Is there a command line tool to merge multiple graphs (in pdf or png format) to one page pdf, probably each fit a cell in a 2x2 table of that page?

Comment: You could possibly set-up a LaTeX document that includes the graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer --- using pdfjam

e.g.

pdfnup --nup 2x2 frag.dat_*pdf

Comment: If he has pdfjam, he probably also has TeXLive, which comes with [pdfnup](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdfnup)